# Use of FFMPEG (compiled exe, not linked DLLs) on a commercial closed-source Windows program

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to use FFMPEG compiled [.exe files](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows) in my commercial Windows OS application and I am wondering if it can be used commercially mainly if:

**a) The compiled ffmpeg.exe is distributed with the application**

I will include ffmpeg.exe binary (got from [official Windows builds URL](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/)) in the application setup file and it will be copied in the same application folder when installed, so the application will run it to perform video conversion tasks.

Or:

**b) The compiled ffmpeg.exe is downloaded from the [official Windows builds URL](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/)**

In this case the setup file of the application will automatically download ffmpeg.exe while the program is being installed (or I can show a window with like "Downloading FFMPEG .exe file...") and then it will be copied in the application folder, so the application will run it to perform video conversion tasks.

I will not use the static linked libraries (dlls) and with option b) I can even not directly distribute ffmpeg.exe file but it will be downloaded from the official URL for Windows builds during installation of the application. In both cases I will write "This application uses FFMPEG" in the application's footer and it will link to FFMPEG website.

Will a) and/or b) case be fine?

Additionally, will I need to buy [x254](https://x264.org/en/) and [x265](https://x265.com/about/license-x265-and-uhdcode-for-your-product-or-service/) licenses also for the above cases?

Thank you everyone.